# Bound difference of squares from difference

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis

I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and I managed to bound
$$
\|f(y) - f(x) \| \leq \delta^2 A
$$
where $\delta > 0$ is small and $A$ is a constant. Given this bound, I would like (I'm hoping) to bound
$$
\left|\, \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\left(\|f(x)\|^2 - \|f(y)\|^2\,\right)\right| \leq \text{Bound}(\delta, \epsilon, A)
$$
where $\epsilon > 0$ is also small. What's the best bound I can get for this expression?

Comment: Your difference bound implies that the values of $f$ are restricted to some hypersphere. However, without knowing anything about which hypersphere, we cannot get a good bound here, as $||f(x)||+||f(y)||$ grows with the distance of the hypersphere from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot get a bound as you wish here. Indeed, take $m=n=1$, and $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, a function that takes values in the interval $[a,a+1]$, such that there are $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x_1)=a$ and $f(x_2)=a+1$. Then $||f(x)-f(y)|| \leq 1$, but
\begin{equation}||f(x_2)||^2-||f(x_1)||^2=(a+1)^2-a^2=(2a+1)\end{equation}

can be arbitrarily large, depending on your choice of $a$.